# Python pip install cannot find module

Tags: python, pip, pylint

So I am trying to install pylint using pip, as my work machine is offline I have downloaded pylint using pip and transferred this using a CD. As part of pylint download it also brought down asteroid, colorama, isort, lazy_object_proxy, McCabe, six, typed ast and wrapt.

However when running the install for pylint using the following command inside the directory with all the above files in:

```
python -m pip install --no-index --find-links . -r requirements.txt
```

This starts to work with it collecting pylint, isort and a couple of others, however after collecting asteroid it goes to collect lazy object proxy (which is in the directory) and gives the following error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lazy-object-proxy (from asteroid<3,>=2.2.0->pylint->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for lazy-object-proxy (from asteroid<3,>=2.2.0->pylint->-r requirements.txt (line 1))

The version of lazy object proxy downloaded is 1.4.1

Im fairly new to this so maybe there is something in this error that highlights why it doesn't see or like the version that is downloaded and in the directory, any help would be much appreciated.

OS is windows 7, running python version 3.6.0

NOTE: even trying to just install lazy object proxy on its own fails saying it doesn't exist, its like its not there although it is in the folder.

Comment: Can you give versions, os, and any environment settings?

Comment: "the requirement laxy-object-proxy". It is just a typo or  you missclick in your requirements.txt

Comment: Thanks both, edited to reflect the typo and version and OS noted, anything else specific Ill add in :)